# Trying to mix discord spa and google sheets spa

Tags: java

Im trying to compile both discord api and google sheets api and I get this error

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
```

and here are the dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.0.0_44'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev516-1.23.0'
}
```

Idk what I'm doing wrong and google isn't helping

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem as well just yesterday and today I found out that I had to compile newer versions of google api client and auth client.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.4'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.30.4'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev581-1.25.0'
}
```

I found this on the Java [Quick Start guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) for Google Sheets.